# Serial communucation rasperberry pi and atmega328p

Tags: raspberry-pi, atmega328p

I have a design system which is generate data. My system include lidar sensor and atmega328p. Atmega is driving my sensor and generate data. No problem is here.
But my aim is data processing in matlab so ı have to communication matlab and my rasperberry wireless because this project is robotic project.

I am using rasperberry pi. Rasperberry pi is the center of system. All data is gather here. it will be analyze and robot will move with this data.Rasper will send data matlab. Matlab will show graph and information also.This is Description of my project.

My problem is raspberry and atmega serial communication. I can't succeed it. How can ı solve this problem. I am beginner rasper and ı don't understand anything. A lot of people says minicom etc. I install it but ı can't see anything. Everybody says the first step is you must connect rx tx pin to rasper and send rasper ls /dev/tty this command and it will output like this /dev/ttyAMA0 but ı can't see this output also.
 raspberry pi

Comment: `ls -l /dev/tty*` I am unfamiliar with RPi, but would expect `ttyS0`(and on) to be the physical UARTS. Becareful that RPi is 3V3 and a lot of other devices is 5V. I believe there is a dedicated RPi stack.

Comment: I know it ı use atmega with 3.3V. I didn't connect UART pin(MOSI,MISO,SCLK). is this solve my problem?

Comment: MOSI,MISO,SCLK != UART. Entirely different interface.

Comment: So ı must connect only rx,tx,gnd pin atmega to rasper. is it true?So why ı can't succeed it. rasper doesnt open any comport ı think.How can ı solve this problem.

Comment: Is the serial port set up for shell login on your Pi? You can check with raspi-config. If it's being used for shell logins you won't be able to use it to talk to your Arduino. What happens if you do "ls -l /dev/tty*"?  Once you identify the serial port on your Pi (the built-in one is apparently /dev/ttyAMA0), you have to hook up TX, RX (TX to RX and vice-versa), and ground. Then just set the baud rate etc. the same on both sides. Should work. http://elinux.org/RPi_Serial_Connection

Comment: when ı send command "ls -l /dev/tty" this is happen  "crw-rw-rw- 1 root root 5, 0 Jan  1  1970 /dev/tty"
ı know it is enable serial com from raspi-config.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's assume you are using python for simplicity.

**Electronic part:**

Connect the serial ports of the ATmega to the serial ports of the Rpi. This is:

Rx <-> Tx

Tx <-> Rx

GND <-> GND

You must be sure of two things to be sure that you are not going to burn anything and the logic levels are correctly recognices: the sources of each one must be the correct one; that means, the Rpi to 5V and the ATMega to whatever it uses. The second is that the grounds must be connected together, if they are not, each one would have a potencial reference different and this could end very badly.

**Raspberry Configuration:**

The raspberry is by default configured to use the serial as console in case you have troubles and you dont find yourself with a screen, ethernet or whatever. To connect it with another device you must first disable this option.

Got to : `sudo raspi-config` and in advance option deactivate the "as serial" option.

You should also check that you have the permissions to talk to tty, for this you can google tty linux and you will find 5k answers of how to add yourself to the correct group.

**Software**

by doing `dmesg | grep tty` you should see your device connected to tty (serial) and the name given by Rpi.

Then you can just use the python pyserial library and talk via serial without any problem. using serial.Write and serial.Read

https://pythonhosted.org/pyserial/

Good Luck!!!

Answer (score 1):

If you are using a recent Raspbian image, the pyserial module should be included in the Python libraries already. With this module, you can open a serial port and communicate with your ATmega chip.

Since the RPi will only be receiving data, from what you have said, you only need to connect the TX pin of the ATmega to the RX pin of the RPi. However, because the ATmega328 outputs 5V TTL signals and the RPi's GPIO pins use 3.3V logic and are not 5V tolerant, you must first use a voltage divider to bring the signal voltage at ATmegas TX pin within the RPis accepted range, to prevent damaging the RX pin.

A pair of resistors with ratio 2:3 will do e.g. 2.2k resistor to GND, 3.3k resistor to the ATmega TX pin and finally the RPi's RX pin connected to the junction between the 2 resistors.
Finally connect the GNDs of both ATmega and RPi together.

Then open the Python 3 IDLE and run this code:

```
import serial

ser = serial.Serial('/dev/ttyAMA0', 9600) # use your ATmegas baud here

while ser.isOpen():
    try:
        print(str(ser.read(), encoding='ascii'))
    except:
        ser.close()
```

If your ATmega is sending anything, you should see it in IDLE. You can stop the program with Ctrl+C.